# Firefox CSS3 isosceles triangle rendering issues

Tags: css, firefox, geometry

I'm trying to create a isosceles triangle using CSS3 and looks like Firefox can't render them properly?

Is there a way of fixing that?

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/WajLY/1/

CSS:

```
.arrow {
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: "";
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 75px solid #222;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

[image]

(Firefox renders the one on the left)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like firefox still has problems with the jagged lines.

**Workaround:**
I came accross this workaround: [Example](http://jsbin.com/opusan/1/edit)
maybe it helps you out - no guarantee.

**Alternative I:**
Make all borders the same size (in your example e.g. 50px) then you will not see the jagged lines. You can scale the size of the arrow with the border-size.

**Alternative II:**
Use an image (should not be a huge request / load time ...)

---

**EDIT:**

Got it work!: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9a6sjtv/)
The trick was to add this line of code: `border-style: solid dotted none;`

**EDIT 2020:**
The hacky workaround is not needed anymore. Updated fiddle.